Intuitive meaning and applications of the Prime Filter Theorem
The prime filter theorem states the following:

Let $(L, \lor, \land)$ be a distributive lattice and $F$ a filter such that $x_0 \notin F$. Then there is a
prime filter $P$ such that $x_0 \not\in P$ and $F \subseteq P$.

The theorem states that any filter that excludes an arbitrary $x_0$ can be expanded into a prime filter which still does not contain $x_0$. In my class, this was presented as a major result in logic. I am simply a student, and I fail to appreciate the importance of this result.
Could anyone elaborate on why such result is considered important? Is it used in proving some other (more obviously important) theorem?

This is false as stated. The bounded lattice with five elements ${0, 1, a, b, c}$ where $a,b,c$ are pairwise incomparable has ${1, a}$ as a filter missing $0$. The filter, however, is already maximal but it is not prime.

Is it possible the result was stated for distributive lattices?

My mistake: the lattice is distributive. Fixed it.

If you are interested in propositional logic, the prime filter theorem is important because it's essentially the Lindenbaum's lemma, that states that any consistent propositional theory can be extended to a complete consistent theory. To prove the Lindenbaum's lemma, you make use of the prime filter theorem and the fact that Boolean algebras are distributive lattices, and moreover that a prime filter in a Boolean algebra is maximal. The Lindenbaum's lemma is pivotal in proving Gödel's completeness theorem.
Here you can find a sketch of the steps needed to prove Lindembaum's lemma:
Lemma Let $B$ be a Boolean algebra and let $F \subseteq B$ be a proper filter. Then there is an ultrafilter $U$ such that $F \subseteq U$.
Proof Since $F$ is proper $0 \notin F$. Since $B$ is a distributive lattice, by the prime filter theorem for distributive lattices, there is a prime filter $U$ such that $F \subseteq U$. Finally it is immediate to see that in a Boolean algebra a prime filter is an ultrafilter.
Lemma Let $T$ be a consistent propositional theory. Then there is a consistent and maximal propositional theory $T'$ such that $T\subseteq T'$.
Proof Let $B$ the Boolean algebra freely generated by a countable set of propositional variables. We define an equivalence relation on $B$ by saying that $\phi \sim \psi$ iff $T \vdash \phi = \psi$. If we define $F$ to be the $\sim$-equivalence class of $\top$, $F$ is a proper filter (verify!) and by the prime filter theorem can be extended to an ultrafilter $U$.

I would appreciate it if you can expand your answer, but I still mark it as correct because it is exactly the kind of information I was after!
